# libre office: remove page number if document has one page only

Tags: libreoffice, page-numbers

I'd like to show page numbers `1/5, 2/5, ...` in the footer of a libre office document. These should generally start on the first page (with `1/5`, e.g.) already. This I can do.

However, if the document has only one page, I do not want to show the `1/1`.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
To clarify: I want to create a template document (it has a header, footer, etc.).  Part of that template document is the page number in the format `<page>/<number of pages>`.  I want the template to be smart enough to show the page number only if the document grows beyond 1 page.

Comment: I don't think there would be an option for that. (maybe you can use macros, but I don't know them in libreoffice at all)

Comment: page number can be hidden on 1st page but doubt if last page only can be hidden on 1st, unless you edit template or footer directly.

Comment: If I create a new document in LibreOffice it doesn't have any page numbers. Please [edit] and clarify your issue.

Comment: added some clarification

Comment: Hint: Use 'Page Styles' in Styles and Formatting. The question is almost two-years old, so I just leave this comment. Not sure if OP is still looking for the answer or already figured out by own since then.

Comment: Related: [How to set different page numbers in footers per page?](https://superuser.com/q/1185110/109256) No wonder I feel familiar, I wrote an answer last year except untested with templates.